# redis does not log bad login attempts

Tags: redis

It seems that Redis does not add log entries for bad login attempts
I have the following redis setup:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
port 6379
requirepass somePassword
logfile /var/log/redis.log
loglevel notice
```

When running `redis-cli -a wrongPassword` and trying to do some operation i get:
`(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.`
But Redis does not add any thing to the log file.

Is it possible to make Redis log bad login attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - Redis does not provide facilities for logging login attempts, whether successful or not.